# swift best way (performance) to search for array element

Tags: arrays, swift, search

I am making an application where I need to get data from an array that can be changed anytime.

For example the array:

```
posts_data: {
  ["id": 1, "text": "Hello"],
  ["id": 4, "text": "Good morning"],
  ["id": 6, "text": "Test"]
}
```

Let's assume I need to change `post 1`'s text, but I don't know the index of it. Then after a while I need to change it again, but the post might be in a different position.

> func doSomeThing() :

```
if let index = posts_data.index(where: { $0.id == 1 }) {
    posts_data[index].text = "NEW TEXT"

    dispatchQueue.global().async {
    // Do something async, then I need to change the text again
    // But I need to search for the index again
    // Because the data source might changed meanwhile

        if let index2 = posts_data.index(where: { $0.id == 1 }) {
            posts_data[index2].text = "AGAIN"
            posts_data[index2].text = "AND AGAIN"
        }
    }

}
```

It's a bit overcomplicated. I came up with the following idea: put the search in a custom class, and return the post if found by id:

```
class MainViewController : UIViewController {
    ...


    func doSomeThing(){
        if PostsClass.shared.getPost(id: 1) == nil {
           return // Just in case if not found
        }

        PostsClass.shared.getPost(id: 1).text = "NEW TEXT"
        dispatchQueue.global().async {
            // Bla bla

            PostsClass.shared.getPost(id: 1).text = "AGAIN"
            PostsClass.shared.getPost(id: 1).text = "AND AGAIN"

        }
    }
}


class PostsClass {
    static let shared = PostsClass()
    func getPost(id: Int) -> Post? {
        if let index = posts_data.index(where: { $0.id == id }) {
            return posts_data[index]
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Is this better or is this a bad idea? Or is there any simpler method than this?

Comment: It is not clear enough, is the Element type of `post_data` (`Post`) a reference type or a value type? Your attempt depends on it. One more, Swift Arrays or Dictionaries are not thread-safe, when you access a single Array (or a Dictionary) from multiple threads, you may need some sort of exclusion control.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is correct if you are trying to search in array.
However, you can use different method to return the post directly:

```
return posts_data.first { $0.id == id }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more efficient way with `first`

```
class PostsClass {
    static let shared = PostsClass()
    func getPost(id: Int) -> Post? {
        return posts_data.first{ $0.id == id }
    }
}
```

And please, this is Swift, name the array `postsData` or simply `posts`

Answer (score 0):

Think you might be looking for something like this :

```
var posts_data: [[String: Any]]  = [
    ["id": 1, "text": "Hello"],
    ["id": 4, "text": "Good morning"],
    ["id": 6, "text": "Test"]
]

var filtered_posts_data: [[String: Any]]   = []

override func viewDidLoad() {

    filtered_posts_data = posts_data.filter({$0.contains(where: { (arg) -> Bool in
        if let valueString = arg.value as? String{
            return valueString.range(of: "hello", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        }else{
            return false
        }
    })})

    print(filtered_posts_data) //[["id": 1, "text": "Hello"]]
}
```